# Spotlight keeps forgetting not to index BOOTCAMP partition

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, spotlight

For special needs, I must mount BOOTCAMP partition as read-writable.

I also add BOOTCAMP partition into Spotlight Privacy because it needs not to be indexed.

But once every few days, Mac forgets about it and BOOTCAMP disappears from Spotlight Privacy.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can add a file named:

```
.metadata_never_index
```

to the root of the volume you don't want indexed.